# Bounding maximum probabilities in sum of i.i.d discrete RVs

Tags: pr.probability

Let $X$ be a a discrete RV with $\mathbb{P}(X=k)<p$ for every $k$ (that's all we know). Taking the independent sum $S=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$, with each $X_i$ distributed like $X$, what can we say about an upper bound for
$$
\max_k \mathbb{P}(S=k) \text{ ?}
$$
If it helps, $n$ is large, but $n\ll \frac1p$. Is it true that
$$
\max_k \mathbb{P}(S=k)\le \frac{cp}{\sqrt{n}}
$$

for some constant $c$?

Addendum: The last line is what you get for fixed $p$ as $n\to\infty$ with CLT. In a sense, this question is asking if we know enough about the convergence of CLT to make this work for $n\ll \frac1p$.

Comment: I expect this holds with $c=\sqrt{6/\pi}$, which is the result when $X$ is a discrete uniform variable on $\{1,2, \ldots 1/p\}$, and $S$ is approximately normal with variance $\sim n/12p^2$.

Comment: That's what I am thinking, $X$ uniform should be the worst, and then you get it. I wonder if here is a theorem out there that implies this, or if it is easyish to prove.

Comment: I would expect a proof to say: we can replace $X$ by a similar variable supported in $\mathbb{Z}/q$ for some $q$, and then we can move the weight in $X$ in steps of $1/q$, getting all the weight as close to the mean as possible subject to the cap on probabilities. The problem is choreographing the steps so each one increases the probability of the mode of $S$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requested estimate follows from a theorem of Kesten [2] about concentration functions.
See in particular the inequality (1.6) on page 135 of [2]. Taking $L=\lambda<1$ in 
this inequality gives the proposed inequality with some constant $c$. The constant $c$ needed  depends on the constant in Rogozin's Theorem [1].

[1] Rogozin, B. A. "An estimate for concentration functions." Theory of Probability & Its Applications 6.1 (1961): 94-97.

[2] Kesten, Harry. "A sharper form of the Doeblin–Levy–Kolmogorov–Rogozin inequality for concentration functions." Mathematica scandinavica 25, no. 1 (1970): 133-144.
See https://www.mscand.dk/article/download/10950/8971

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for asking. This beautiful line of work by Levy, Kolmogorov, Rogozin and Kesten should be better known. It has impressed me since I was a graduate student.